# VBA: Getting rid of generated extra sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I do not know how did this happen. I have tried "Remove Sheet1" but it is not available for me to click. May i know what is the problem?

[image: Extra Sheet1]

[image: Remove Sheet1]

Comment: How did it get there? The weird thing is that it has a Workbook icon, not a Worksheet icon.

Answer (score 0):

Having seen the icon of `Sheet1`, it's actually a workbook. It's like a "ghost worksheet".

[image]

Your Excel file is most likely corrupted in some way. I'd suggest you export all modules and copy them to the proper worksheet/workbook code into a new file and then delete the corrupted file.